# Select ENV/ARG in Dockerfile depending on build ARG

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I currently have two Dockerfiles that are identical except for some ENV vars at the beginning that have different values. I want to combine them into one Dockerfile and select the ENV vars depending on one build-arg / ARG instead.

I tried something like this with $target being either WIN or UNIX:

```
FROM alpine
ARG target
ARG VAR1_WIN=Value4Win
ARG VAR1_UNIX=Value4Unix
ARG VAR1=VAR1_$target
ARG VAR1=${!VAR1}
RUN echo $VAR1
```

But it throws an error: `failed to process "${!VAR1}": missing ':' in substitution`
I tried a lot but I'm unable to double expand `$VAR1`.
How do I do this correctly? Thx.

Comment: Can you include your build command that specifies the args? Are you building with `--build-arg` ?

Comment: I used `docker build --build-arg target=WIN .`

Comment: What is the `!` in `${!VAR1}` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Just remove the `!`.

Comment: It is supposed to double expand VAR1. With just `${VAR1}` I get `VAR1_WIN` as result instead of `Value4Win`

Comment: Can you not pass in `Value4Win` or `Value4Unix` directly with `--build-arg` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the conditional syntax, there is a pattern you can use with a multi-stage build:

```
# ARG defined before the first FROM can be used in FROM lines
ARG target

# first base image for WIN target
FROM alpine as base-WIN
# switching to ENV since ARG doesn't pass through to the next stage
ENV VAR1=Value4Win

# second base image for UNIX target
FROM alpine as base-UNIX
ENV VAR1=Value4Unix

# select one of the above images based on the value of target
FROM base-${target} as release
RUN echo $VAR1
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect! A small downside is that always all intermediate containers are built. However, since they are just setting ENV vars, that's not a real problem.

Comment: Switching to BuildKit would result in only the dependent stages getting built.

Answer (score 0):

The double expand syntax `${!VAR}` only works in `bash`, while `Dockerfile` is not parsed by shell. According to the [docker manual](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution), `Dockerfile` does not support double expand.

Note that `alpine` use `ash` instead of `bash`, so it does not support `${!VAR}` either. You have to use `eval` + `echo`. Try `RUN VAR1="$(eval "echo \$$VAR1")"; echo $VAR1`.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't pass `Value4Win` or `Value4Unix` directly via `--build-arg`, here is one way:

```
FROM alpine

ARG target
ARG VAR1=Value4${target}
RUN echo $VAR1
```

Doing a `docker build --build-arg target=WIN .` gives:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN echo $VAR1
 ---> Running in 6e94bc28d459
Value4WIN
```